# Валидация чекбокса

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как сделать проверку на несколько чекбоксов, что если хотя бы один отмечен то форма отправляется? Первая проверка идёт по сабмиту если отправляем пустую форму, вторая по чекбоксам, если один выбран то убираем ошибку. Один чекбокс должен быть обязательным. Запутался совсем...

```js
const checkboxWrapper = document.querySelector("form");
const checkbox = document.querySelectorAll("[data-checkbox]");
const error = document.querySelector("[data-error]");

checkboxWrapper.addEventListener("submit", (evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault();
  
  checkbox.forEach((input, i) => {
    if (checkbox[i].checked && checkbox[i].checked > 0) {
      error.textContent = ""
    } else {
      error.textContent = "Ошибка"
    }
  });
});

checkbox.forEach((input, i) => {
  checkbox[i].addEventListener("change", () => {
    if (checkbox[i].checked) {
      error.textContent = ""
    } else {
      error.textContent = "Ошибка"
    }
  })
});
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <div>
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="check-1" data-checkbox="">
    <label for="check-1">Checkbox 1</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="check-2" data-checkbox="">
    <label for="check-2">Checkbox 2</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="check-3" data-checkbox="">
    <label for="check-3">Checkbox 3</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="check-4" data-checkbox="">
    <label for="check-4">Checkbox 4</label>
  </div>
  <span data-error=""></span>
  <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Заводим флаг
2. Устанавливаем его в `false`
3. Пробегаем по списку чекбоксов
4. Как только нашли включенный чекбокс, флаг переводим в `true`
5. После цикла проверяем флаг и производим действие

Ну и всю проверку лучше вынести в отдельную функцию, чтобы вызывать ее из разных мест.

```js
const checkboxWrapper = document.querySelector("form");
const checkbox = document.querySelectorAll("[data-checkbox]");
const error = document.querySelector("[data-error]");

function testCheckboxes() {
  let checked = false;
  checkbox.forEach((input) => {
    if (input.checked)
      checked = true;
  });
  if (checked) {
    error.textContent = ""
  } else {
    error.textContent = "Ошибка"
  }
  return checked;
}

checkboxWrapper.addEventListener("submit", (evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault();
  testCheckboxes();
});

checkbox.forEach((input) => {
  input.addEventListener("change", (evt) => {
    testCheckboxes();
  });
});
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <div>
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="check-1" data-checkbox="">
    <label for="check-1">Checkbox 1</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="check-2" data-checkbox="">
    <label for="check-2">Checkbox 2</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="check-3" data-checkbox="">
    <label for="check-3">Checkbox 3</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="check-4" data-checkbox="">
    <label for="check-4">Checkbox 4</label>
  </div>
  <span data-error=""></span>
  <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Просто проверяем количество отмеченных `checkbox` в форме и, на основании этого, показываем/скрываем предупреждение:

```js
const checkboxWrapper = document.querySelector('form');
const checkbox = [...document.querySelectorAll('[data-checkbox]')];
const error = document.querySelector('[data-error]');

checkboxWrapper.addEventListener('submit', (evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault();
  invalid();
});

checkbox.forEach((input) => {
  input.addEventListener('change', invalid);
});

function invalid() {
  error.textContent = ([...checkboxWrapper.querySelectorAll('[data-checkbox]:checked')].length) ? '' : 'Ошибка';
}
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <div>
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="check-1" data-checkbox="">
    <label for="check-1">Checkbox 1</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="check-2" data-checkbox="">
    <label for="check-2">Checkbox 2</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="check-3" data-checkbox="">
    <label for="check-3">Checkbox 3</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="check-4" data-checkbox="">
    <label for="check-4">Checkbox 4</label>
  </div>
  <span data-error=""></span>
  <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Comment: есть мини - баг. Если сначала чекнуть, а потом анчекнуть 1 чекбокс )

Comment: Не совсем понял про что вы, вроде работает как надо

Comment: Аа, если вы так и задумывали...